# Bouncy Castle and CryptoJS vs Pycryptodome and Cryptography - who's right and how to decrypt the data in Python?

Tags: python, aes, bouncycastle, pycryptodome, cbc-mode

Let me explain. I have some data encrypted by Bouncy Caste library (AES 128 CBC).
I am able to decompress the data using Crypto.js:

```
var CryptoJS = require('crypto-js')

const ivHexString = '4d055a9e07e7db37297dd20cc73c4cc4'
const keyHexString = 'aab60badba8587c95e36c5cf6cf736b9'

const decrypt = u8arr => { 
    const wordArray = arr => CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(arr)
    const ciphertext = wordArray(u8arr)
    const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(ivHexString)
    const key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(keyHexString)
    const cipherTextParam = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({ ciphertext })
    const cipherParams = {         
        iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    }
    const output = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipherTextParam, key, cipherParams)
    return output.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)
}

const data = 'CYkJIz1qptjyjNh4VpzODnVq94JLIx37B0677lYlMJhFtOA6ZFL7CY0M6wRyZlW5pfSorSEDEUbw9EqDePLUvSCwtTsB6CXnVL2+TNvYaffnV/lpjfEAoHANiUxgbBabY3k3BBUAj8RXDmLIQw/bftJcvXw5egS7U0ucb0lDKByqSrMT1DaFDrOHnjO7r2ahZIgZ2G/wHcNwDjloGPvkjGAbwqWfdHaazflGzGTcgXb/PY4UtThba2t8PZBmF8Injiu8As2jl9mt+oC/QvhgJhuIOqJ69Hnt7EoGX4MNX0e/a5qjCHEMOtC4v3gW6sozuVoozXL3uNYHtfsPfnCD2g=='
const uint8arr = Uint8Array.from(Buffer.from(data, 'base64'))
const d = decrypt(uint8arr)
console.log(d)
```

This is working good. The expected result is:

```
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
```

But the result in Pycryptodome or Cryptograhy is different and they complain about padding:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util import Padding
import base64

def decrypt():
    iv = '4d055a9e07e7db37297dd20cc73c4cc4'
    key = 'aab60badba8587c95e36c5cf6cf736b9'
    data_b64 =  'CYkJIz1qptjyjNh4VpzODnVq94JLIx37B0677lYlMJhFtOA6ZFL7CY0M6wRyZlW5pfSorSEDEUbw9EqDePLUvSCwtTsB6CXnVL2+TNvYaffnV/lpjfEAoHANiUxgbBabY3k3BBUAj8RXDmLIQw/bftJcvXw5egS7U0ucb0lDKByqSrMT1DaFDrOHnjO7r2ahZIgZ2G/wHcNwDjloGPvkjGAbwqWfdHaazflGzGTcgXb/PY4UtThba2t8PZBmF8Injiu8As2jl9mt+oC/QvhgJhuIOqJ69Hnt7EoGX4MNX0e/a5qjCHEMOtC4v3gW6sozuVoozXL3uNYHtfsPfnCD2g=='
    data = base64.b64decode(data_b64)
    iv = bytes.fromhex(iv)
    key = bytes.fromhex(key)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    ct = cipher.decrypt(data)
    t = Padding.unpad(ct, AES.block_size)
    return t

res_b64 = decrypt()
res = base64.b64encode(res_b64)
print(res)
```

Do they have diffrent padding implementations? Where is the difference?

BouncyCastle code (without salt):

```
public class CryptoUtil {

    private CryptoUtil() {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }

    public static byte[] encryptAes(byte[] data, char[] password) throws Exception {
        ParametersWithIV key = (ParametersWithIV) getAesPasswdKey(password);
        BufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CBCBlockCipher(new AESFastEngine()));
        cipher.init(true, key);
        byte[] result = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(data.length)];
        int len = cipher.processBytes(data, 0, data.length, result, 0);
        cipher.doFinal(result, len);
        return result;
    }

    public static byte[] decryptAes(byte[] data, char[] password) throws Exception {
        ParametersWithIV key = (ParametersWithIV) getAesPasswdKey(password);
        BufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CBCBlockCipher(new AESFastEngine()));
        cipher.init(false, key);
        byte[] result = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(data.length)];
        int len = cipher.processBytes(data, 0, data.length, result, 0);
        int doFinalLen = cipher.doFinal(result, len);
        byte[] ret = new byte[len + doFinalLen];
        System.arraycopy(result, 0, ret, 0, ret.length);
        return ret;
    }


    private static CipherParameters getAesPasswdKey(char[] passwd) throws Exception {
        PBEParametersGenerator generator = new PKCS12ParametersGenerator(new SHA1Digest());
        generator.init(PBEParametersGenerator.PKCS12PasswordToBytes(passwd), SALT, 1);
        ParametersWithIV key = (ParametersWithIV) generator.generateDerivedParameters(128, 128);
        return key;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the BouncyCastle code for encryption.

Comment: The code was added.

Comment: Please post the code that uses the posted key, IV and plaintext to generate the posted ciphertext. If this is really the Java code, post password and salt. The point here is to reproduce the ciphertext with the input data!

Comment: Are you serious? You can test it using any key and salt.

Comment: You have ct in js and python code.

Comment: I don't want to check it with any data, I want to reproduce your ciphertext with your input data!

Comment: In case you haven't noticed, the Java code uses a key derivation function.

Comment: I think it won't be any difference with your data.

Comment: I have noticed. Actually generated key and iv are always the same, but this is not an answer to my question.

Comment: Your ciphertext CYkJ... cannot be decrypted with the Java code with the posted key and IV, but throws an *InvalidCipherTextException* (pad block corrupted). For the same reason, the Python code also returns a corresponding error message. The CryptoJS code returns a result because it ignores the invalid padding, and determines the number of characters to remove from the last corrupted byte 0x90 = 144, which is why a large part of the ciphertext is removed. When consistent data is used (or padding is disabled during decryption), all three codes (Java, CryptoJS, Python) provide the same result.

Comment: By the way, after you changed the CryptoJS code, you forgot to update the ciphertext (it's ueVji... instead of Gskd...).

Comment: Gsk... is a result (raw data, just encoded as b64 string) not a ct, but your intuition was good. Now I think the problem is the data.  I have no opportunity to test now, but i will check it very soon. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, a typo on my part. But the important thing is that Gsk... is the decrypted data of the old and not the current CryptoJS code. With respect to future readers, this should be corrected as it is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

The raw data is decrypted in an identical manner in both implementations - but it does not have correct PKCS7-padding - at least not when interpreting all of the `data` as ciphertext. The last 16 bytes are, in both cases, `3137f423fe539c956832f442480a3690`. This is not correct PKCS7-padding... The last byte should be in the range 01-10 (hex), and then repeated 'backwards' for the number of bytes is represents.

The Crypto-JS implementation though, returns 112 bytes of ciphertext, it was expected to return 256 - 16, since that's the length of the cipher text - if the `data` was in fact raw AES cipher-text. But it's not.

Comment: Although CryptoJS and Pycryptodome unpadding implementations are different (or written in a different manner) now I think the problem is the data. I suppose the data were encrypted using different passwords, so the key and iv are simply not matched with the data at all.

Comment: CryptoJS seems to try to be too smart somehow... Try to change the padding scheme to none in both implementations, and you should see that they actually decrypt to exactly the same data. For some reason, CryptoJS interprets it as something more than just a raw encrypted data stream of encrypted blocks, and then reports no error - and only 112 bytes of plaintext. Without knowing more of the source of the data, I don't think I'll get any further.

Comment: Actually... As @Topaco commented, the CryptoJS implementation is in fact to my suprise broken! It should report padding error as the others. First of all, 144 is out of range for the block size, second of all, the padding is supposed to consist of the same byte value for all the padding bytes. Not often that you'll find a reasonably well reputed crypto library with such a glaring bug.